# creating an array and looping through it in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I created an array. I want to push things into the array and when I click on "pic2" have it run the "runShadow" function... I want the function to make visible any of the objects that have been pushed into the array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var shadowArray = [];

    function runShadow() { // jquery- ".each"? look this up in stackoverflow!
        console.log("functionWorking!");
        for (var i = 0; i < shadowArray.length; i++) {
            shadowArray[i].animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 1500, "linear");
        }
    }
    $("#pic1a").click(function () {
        $('#pic2').fadeIn(1500);
        $('#pic1').animate({
            top: -100,
            left: -1000
        }, 1500, "linear");
        $('#pic1a').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1500, "linear");
        $('#pic1b').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1500, "linear");
        $('#pic1c').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1500, "linear");
        $('#pic1d').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1500, "linear");
        $('#pic1e').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1500, "linear");
        $('#pic1f').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1500, "linear");

        shadowArray.push("pic1a");
        console.log(shadowArray);
        console.log("WORKING!");

    });
    $("#pic2").click(function () {
        $('#pic2').fadeOut(1500);
        $('#pic1').animate({
            top: -770,
            left: -800
        }, 1500, "linear");
        runShadow();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$("#"+shadowArray[i]).animate(...)
```

Comment: yes that did it! thank you!!...if you see this comment, do you mind telling me what the hashtag is for? I don't think I understand that part... I do see that the array had to be wrapped in jquery though... very cool. thanks again !!!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ - in this case http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/